# How to use Clauses with API REST Neo4J?

Tags: rest, neo4j, cypher

I have a complexe request that perfectly works in Neo4j Browser that I want to use through API Rest, but there are **Clauses**  I can't cope with.

The syntax looks like :

> MATCH p=()-[*]->(node1)
>
> WHERE …
>
> WITH...
>
> ....
>
> FOREACH … SET …

I constructed the query with Transactional Cyper as i have been suggested by @cybersam, but I don't manage to use more than one clause anyway.

To give an exemle, if I write the statement in one line :

```
    :POST /db/data/transaction/commit {

    "statements": [
    {
       "statement": "MATCH p = (m)-[*]->(n:SOL {PRB : {PRB1}}) WHERE nodes (p) 
MATCH q= (o:SOL {PRB : {PRB2}} RETURN n, p, o, q;",

 "parameters": {"PRB1": "Title of problem1", "PRB2": "Title of problem2"}
    }   ],   

"resultDataContents": ["graph"] }
```

I shall obtain :

> {"results":[],"errors":[{"code":"Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError","message":"Invalid input 'R': expected whitespace, comment, ')' or a relationship pattern (line 1, column 90 (offset: 89))\r\n\"MATCH p = (m)-[*]->(n:SOL {PRB : {PRB1}}) WHERE nodes (p) MATCH q= (o:SOL {PRB : {PRB2}} RETURN n, p, o, q;\"\r\n                                                                                          ^"}]}

But if I put it in several lines, :

```
 :POST /db/data/transaction/commit {

 "statements": [
    {
      "statement": "MATCH p = (m)-[*]->(n:SOL {PRB : {PRB1}})
 WHERE nodes (p) 
 MATCH q= (o:SOL {PRB : {PRB2}} 
 RETURN n, p, o, q;",

"parameters": {"PRB1": "Title of problem1", "PRB2": "Title of problem2"}
    }
  ],

  "resultDataContents": ["graph"]
}
```

it is said :

> {"results":[],"errors":[{"code":"Neo.ClientError.Request.InvalidFormat","message":"Unable
>   to deserialize request: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code
>   10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string
>   value\n at [Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@41fa906c; line: 4, column:
>   79]"}]}

Please, I need your help !

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Transaction Cypher HTTP API](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/http-api/#http-api-transactional), you could just pass the same Cypher statement to the API.

To quote from [this section of the doc](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/http-api/#rest-api-begin-and-commit-a-transaction-in-one-request), here is an example of the simplest way to do that:

> Begin and commit a transaction in one request If there is no need to
>   keep a transaction open across multiple HTTP requests, you can begin a
>   transaction, execute statements, and commit with just a single HTTP
>   request.
>
> **Example request**
>
> - POST `http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit`
> - Accept: `application/json; charset=UTF-8`
> - Content-Type: `application/json`
>
>   ```
>   {
>     "statements" : [ {
>       "statement" : "CREATE (n) RETURN id(n)"
>     } ]
>   }
>   ```
>
> **Example response**
>
> - 200: OK
> - Content-Type: `application/json`
>
>   ```
>   {
>     "results" : [ {
>       "columns" : [ "id(n)" ],
>       "data" : [ {
>         "row" : [ 6 ],
>         "meta" : [ null ]
>       } ]
>     } ],
>     "errors" : [ ]
>   }
>   ```

Comment: So should I divide each part of the request in a specific statement ? How the statements would be linked together and connected with datas analysed ?

Comment: You pass your entire statement (in your example you have just one, consisting of multiple clauses).

Comment: With Transactional Cypher, it does'nt work also when I use more than one Clause. Read Upgrade of this question above...

Comment: You need to fix your Cypher code. It has numerous syntax issues. A `WHERE` clause needs to evaluate to a boolean value. What is your `WHERE` clause trying to test? Also, you are missing a right parenthesis at the end of your second `MATCH` clause. Test your Cypher using the neo4j browser, or at http://console.neo4j.org before you use it with the API. Finally, you should avoid trying to do 2 unrelated queries in the same statement, as that will cause a [cartesian product](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/cross-product-cypher-queries-will-not-perform-well/).

Comment: Your advices helped me to find out the problem I encountered. Thanks a lot !